# ActiveAdmin: Filter by count of child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin, ransack

In a Ruby on Rails app that heavily relies on ActiveAdmin, I have a Sponsor model, which is associated with a Sponsorship model. One `sponsor` can sponsor many children, so one `sponsor` can have many `sponsorships`.

What I would like to do, is to be able, on the Sponsor index page, to filter out sponsors by the number of sponsorships they have. So that, for example, I want to see only those sponsors who have more than one sponsorship, or less than five, and so on. You get the idea. In Ruby-speak, I want a filter that would do something along the following lines:

```
Sponsor.all.select { |sp| sp.sponsorships.count > 1 }
```

I found out that it is, in fact, quite hard to do. Default ActiveAdmin’s filters work on attributes of a particular model (or its children models), and not on custom methods, while I need to filter precisely by a custom method. So this is the filter in ActiveAdmin’s combined view/controller sponsor.rb file:

```
filter :sponsorships_count, label: 'Sponsorships', as: :numeric
```

where `:sponsorships_count` is not an attribute of the Sponsor model.

I tried to use Ransacker (it seems [some people have had success with it](http://cavewall.jaguardesignstudio.com/2014/05/01/activeadmin-filters-with-ransack/)), but couldn't figure out the proper syntax. Others had some luck specifying filters as custom (using `as: custom` syntax such as [here](https://gist.github.com/rdj/1057991) and providing the name of a model scope as a filter name), but this didn't work for me (the app is using ActiveAdmin version 1.0.0.pre which is reported not to work with this approach).

Help, somebody?

Comment: check this https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3712 for solution