# In Ransack, how to write a custom ransacker to search by count of associated models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arel, ransack

(This is a more specified version of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663015/activeadmin-filter-by-count-of-child-objects) that I asked previously but that has not received any answers; I hope it's not against SO’s rules)

Given that I have a Rails 4 app that has a `Sponsor` model and a `Sponsorship` model, so that a `sponsor` has many `sponsorships`, and a `sponsorship` belongs to a `sponsor`, I want to find sponsors with a number of sponsorships greater than, equal to, or less than a certain number. In order to do this, I am trying to use Ransack, a search gem that the app employs.

Here is the command that in rails console does what I need (in this particular case, returns sponsors who have more than 1 sponsorship):

```
Sponsor.joins(:sponsorships).group("sponsors.id").having("count(sponsorships.id) > ?",1)
```

Could you please help me build a [ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers) out of this command so that I could use Ransack to perform this function?

*(I was told that my problem is better solved with an entirely different approach, by using count_cache in Rails, but still I would love to see this done with Ransack, if nothing else then as an instructive example.)*

Comment: So it seems doing this takes a bit of configuration and a few additional gems. All I can do is provide a blog post as I have not implemented something like this. Checkout [Scopes with Ransack](https://coderwall.com/p/4zz6ca/scopes-with-ransack)

Comment: Wow, I thought ransackers, when tweaked appropriately, can do this on their own. The link is useful; thank you for it.